# Reupload binary before app submission

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I've uploaded a binary of my iOS app. I have yet to submit my app for review. This will be a brand new app that is yet in the App Store. I have recently found a bug that I have now fixed and would like to upload this new binary before submission. Obviously I can submit it for review then reject but I would prefer to simply upload the new binary before submission in the first place. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Apple recently updated their instructions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33

Comment: @user523234 You should make an answer of your comment so that it can be accepted as such.

Comment: Agreed. Publish an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Per OP requested:

Apple has recently updated their instructions and IMO it is much better than any previous documents:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33